# Add/ remove custom validators to form array in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to set/ take away custom validators for different elements in a form array that can change around, so far what I have tried to do is create a switch statement and loop through all of the input types that are set so I could set the validation rule as well as send a message to the user if the rule isn't met. The problem I am having is the form is initialized before the form data is set.

So my question is how can I loop through the array and set the validation rules. If someone could let me know if im along the right tracks with using a switch statement but have code in the wrong place or if there is a different and better approach it would be most helpful thank you

```js
export class ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public fieldList: any;
  types: Array<any>;
  formData: any;
  Param: string;
  setData: any;
  formLabelNames: any;

  get contactFormGroup() {
    return this.form.get('inputs') as FormArray;
  }
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private api: FormService,
    private notifiy: NotificationService,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      organization: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      inputs: this.fb.array([this.createForm()])
    });
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.Param = params.get('id');
      this.getForm(this.Param);
    });
    // set fieldslist to this field
    this.fieldList = this.form.get('inputs') as FormArray;
  }

  // formgroup
  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      type: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      value: ['', this.validators()]
    });
  }

  getForm(id) {
    this.api.getForm(id).subscribe(
      (data: any) => this.setForm(data)
    );
  }
getFieldsFormGroup(index): FormGroup {
    const formGroup = this.fieldList.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    return formGroup;
  }
  getContactsFormGroup(index): FormGroup {
    const formGroup = this.fieldList.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    return formGroup;
  }
  setForm(data) {
    const d = data.results;
    this.setData = d;
    this.formLabelNames = d[0].fields;
    this.form.patchValue({
      name: [d[0].form_name],
      organization: [d[0].org],
    });
    this.form.setControl('inputs', this.setExistingFields(d[0].fields));
  }
setExistingFields(fields: any): FormArray {
  const formArray = new FormArray([]);
  this.fieldList = formArray;
  fields.forEach(f => {
    formArray.push(this.fb.group({
      name: f.name,
      type: f.type,
      value: f.value
    }));
  });
  return formArray;
}
/* This is where I have tried to create a switch statement but I get a undefined error because the setform function is being called after this one */
validators() {
   this.formLabelNames.type.forEach((field: any) => {
     switch (field.type) {
       case 'email':
     }
   });
}
submit() {
  if (this.form.valid) {
  const formId = this.Param;
  const local = this.auth.decodePayload();
  const userId = local.sub;
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
  this.api.sendForm(this.form.value, formId, userId).subscribe();
  this.form.reset();
  } else {
    this.notifiy.showFailure('Form is not valid', 'Error');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems, as far as I can judge:

1. You don't initialize neither the formControls nor the formArray correctly inside of you formGroup. It should rather look like this:

```js
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl( "", {validators: [Validators.required]}),
      organization: new FormControl( "", {validators: [Validators.required]}),
      inputs: this.fb.array([new FormControl(), new FormControl()]),
    });
```

Besides: What is the point of using a formArray when it consists of only one formGroup?

2. Off course you can set the validators for any abstractControl be it a formControl or a formGroup. For the array it would look like something like this:

```js
    this.formArray.controls.map((ctrl) => {
      ctrl.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.email]);
    });
```

3. It doesn't matter where in the component class you put your method. Though it surely matters when that method is invoked!

Comment: If im not mistaken because I am using angulars form builder I though I don't have to use new formControl, the code for setting the form values works perfectly it's just trying to validate each field in the inputs array with the correct vaildators for instance one form can have email, phone home address where as another form can have phone, social security number, DOB